# Facebook Login Button Alignment iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

I need some help on aligning the facebook login button programatically. 
Here is the code that facebook sdk gives you and places it in the center at the top of the storyboard.

I want to align it at a specific spot towards the bottom of my storyboard. This is where the SDK places it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzIzN.png ......Here is where i want to place it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYR09.png

Thanks folks.

```
 //Facebook Login Button
    FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
    // Align the button in the center horizontally
    loginView.frame = CGRectOffset(loginView.frame, (self.view.center.x - (loginView.frame.size.width / 2)), 5);
    [self.view addSubview:loginView];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `center` property instead of the frame. That is how I do it.

```
loginView.center = CGPointMake(selfWidth /2, selfHeight - 40);
```

Comment: Compiler gives me: Use of undeclared Identifier "selfWidth"

Comment: `selfWidth` and `selfHeight` are CGFloat variables I have created that store the `self.view.frame.size.width` and `self.view.frame.size.height`.

Comment: Thank you buddy,I didn't know that. It works great now! I have another question btw if you could help that'd be great! Do you know how to create users using the facebook sdk? i'm making this app and I want to create user profiles and a home feed but I don't know how to go about creating users... Thanks again pal

Comment: Thanks dude! Do you have any useful tutorials/books for creating social networking apps using objective c and the facebook sdk?

Comment: I have combed through all the documentation I could, and unfortunately, you **cannot** create users for Facebook on your own. The only possible solution I see is, redirecting the user to Facebook itself, or let the `loginView` invoke it's own `openURL:` and taking the user to the login / signup page.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I believe that Parse lets app users to create an account for an my application using their email address and/or Facebook. That is what I'm trying to do. I've already let the users login to my app using facebook, but now I'm trying to enable them to login using their email address. Thanks !

Comment: Oh, you meant sign up for your app through Facebook. I thought you wanted to sign up users **for** Facebook from your app. In your case, you don't need Parse. The `FBLoginViewDelegate`method `loginViewFetchedUserInfo:user:` method returns all relevant data you need for signup, including name, email, gender, DOB, etc. I can post sample code if you want.

Comment: The above is useful if you have `FBLoginView`. If not, you can simply use the Facebook Graph API, for requesting user data. Study it [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph)

Comment: That's right. I just enabled users to create accounts for my app using facebook. However, what I need now is to enable users to create accounts for my app without using facebook. Just by using their email :)